# Vaadin Multi-Select Combo Box expand visible area

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

By default, the [Multi-Select Combo Box](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/multi-select-combo-box) hides elements that do not fit within its visible area (as shown in Figure #1).

Is there a way to configure/style the `Multi-Select Combo Box` component to automatically expand its visible area to display all selected items within it (as shown in Figure #2)?

[image]

**UPDATED**

I created 2 files and placed them there:

[image]

Insed of the `styles.css` I added the following:

```
@import url('./combobox/vaadin-multi-select-combo-box.css');
@import url('./combobox/vaadin-multi-select-combo-box-container.css');
```

and nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment. There is a feature request ticket that you can  at https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/4625, and there's a comment in there with some CSS-based hacks to achieve it today.

Comment: Thank you! Should this work for Vaadin 24.2.0 ? I added 2 files:

`vaadin-multi-select-combo-box.css
vaadin-multi-select-combo-box-container.css`

to themes\THEME_NAME\components folder but nothing happens..

Comment: Yeah that's the wrong way: the CSS provided in that issue is GLOBAL css, not Shadow DOM CSS, so it needs to be in a normal stylesheet, e.g. styles.css. You can rewrite it to work in shadow CSS, but global CSS is the recommended approach in V24, for which we provide selector documentation, etc.

Comment: I apologize, it looks like I'm still doing something wrong. Could you please take a look at my updated question? I implemented the mentioned steps there, but still without any result. What am I doing wrong? I use styles from the following comment: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/4625#issuecomment-1542230857

Comment: Ah well THAT version actually DOES use shadow DOM CSS – didn't notice that because I just checked the examples provided in earlier comments. Rule of thumb: whenever you see ::part() it's global CSS, and whenever you see :host it's shadow DOM CSS. So you do need to put those in the components folder. Which Vaadin version are you using btw?

Comment: If it's V24, you might need to disable the pre-compiled frontend bundle for shadow DOM stylesheets to be applied: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/configuration/development-mode#disable-precompiled-bundle